# Is there a way to run separate set of processes with docker dynamically?

Tags: docker

So suppose I have a machine and I need this machine to be able to work in three modes: A, B, C.

In mode A it should run one set of processes. In mode B - another set of processes. And in mode C it should run both sets.

The modes should be chosen dynamically from the web interface.

Comment: Confusing question ... why don't you just run different dockerfiles depending on what you want the machine to do?

Comment: Sometimes users want machine to do one thing, sometimes the other and they dynamically changing it.

Comment: So.... @erjiang's point is create an image for each application and then run whatever your customer specifies. Much simpler and easier to test compared to a multi-purpose image.

Answer (score 1):

Install programs needed by A and B, and supervisor

http://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

tweak supervisor, so that according to some event, presence of file somewhere, value of an environment variable or any other event, you run either A, B, or C.

Comment: Also, I've seen the phusion devs recommend runit, but I've no experience of it myself.

Comment: Um... That's basically how it works right now. However all programs should then be in one container then, which I don't like. Supervisord could be started on host machine, but then a container should be able to send a signal to host. What this signal should be? I don't know if I can change environment variable on host from a container. I probably can create a file, but that's looks ugly.

Comment: @user1685095 you've lost me - myself and I think the answerer were assuming the "mode" was chosen on container creation, in which case you use the cmd or entrypoint script to set the "mode". If you need to start one of 3 different containers or change containers dynamically, that is something very different.

Comment: It is indeed. And the term "dynamically" was named twice in my question.

Comment: Err, so you're asking if you can dynamically change the processes in a container without it having the programs for all the processes?